# How to add json data into my xcode project?

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a simple Pokedex which allows a user to switch pokemon's name between English and Japanese using Swift. I found [this source](https://github.com/fanzeyi/pokemon.json) on the internet and there are Pokemon names both in English and Japanese in the pokedex.json file and Pokemon images in the Images folder, so I'm planning to use the source, but the problem is I'm not sure how to access the data without endpoint.

Usually, I use the swiftyJOSN and the Alamofire in order to make a request to API and parse the JSON data, however, the source doesn't have an API endpoint. So that is why I'm confused about how to access the data without any GET request.

I guess somehow I need to put the pokedex.json and other image files into my code project and make my code accessible to data (sorry I'm not sure). So, if I'm correct, can anyone tell me how can I import the file to my project? On the other hand, if I'm trying to do something completely wrong, could anyone please tell me about that?

Also, I'd like to know how can I access the data in the JSON file using Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can ship a file as a resource inside your app bundle.
Here's how you can do it:

1. In Xcode, create a group inside your project and give it a descriptive name, for example "Resources".
2. Download the pokedex.json file from your source.
3. Drag and drop this `pokedex.json` file into that group from Finder to Xcode. When the file adding dialog appears, be sure to check the "Copy items if needed" checkbox and that your main target is selected.
4. In the code, you read the resource like this:

```swift
guard let pokedexFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pokedex", ofType: "json"),
    let pokedexData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: pokedexFilePath) else
{
    // TODO: handle error appropriately
    return
}
// Now you can parse pokedexData with SwiftyJSON, Codable or whatever you prefer.
```

However if you need to ship image files with your app, you may find using an asset catalog (the blue Assets.xcassets folder in your Xcode project) more convenient rather than using the approach I described above. In asset catalog, you can specify different versions of the same image for different screens or interface themes and even have localized versions of the same image if needed. When using an asset catalog, you can create an image in your code by just calling `UIImage(named: "your_image_name_in_the_catalog")`.